# How do I comply to GPL in case of Appliance?

Tags: licensing, open-source, gpl

We are developing an enterprise network appliance which has got some GPL softwares like linux and apache and some others with APL license.

But the core of the service is proprietary software and access is provided only via a web interface.

My query is what all I need to do in order to comply with GPL license in this scenario. Would providing a list of Third party softwares used in the appliance in the web interface be sufficient?

Comment: Don't have time for a complete answer, but no, providing just a list of 3rd-party software is not sufficient. TTBOMK, you also need to offer your customers a way to obtain the source of the 3rd-party software (and possibly even a way to install home-built versions of it).

Comment: 1) Depends a lot on how closely those different software parts are linked. 2) Which version of the GPL? GPLv3 has some extra requirements, related to customers being able to install their own version of the GPLed software.

Comment: You may be getting into a sufficiently complex licensing situation where it may be a good idea to list all the products used, their licenses and hire a lawyer to review the and identify what you need to do to be in compliance with the licenses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are selling the appliance to your customers you are "conveying" the software to your customers and will need comply with the licenses (GPL or otherwise) for all software installed on the device.

For all of the common licenses this means you must include the Copyright and license details for all packages in your documentation. For the GPL this means you must provide the source or an offer to provide the source to your customers.

If you have included modified GPL code you must make the modified sources available.

If your proprietary software could be considered a derived work of GPL software you will need to provide the source for your proprietary software.  However, just installing it on a linux machine and using the standard libraries does not make your software a derived work.

Comment: It's important to note the difference between GPLv2 and GPLv3 here. For GPLv2 (Linux) the sources have to be provided, but method of installing new binaries on the device does not. For GPLv3 (most libraries usually used on Linux) such method must be provided.

Comment: You are correct, that is why I would advocate using FreeBSD or other BSD and/or Apache licensed software on appliances.

Comment: Craig, We checked with some Licensing lawyers as well. Our product is not a derivative and what they have suggested is to put up an page on web interface which lists Third party software , licensing terms and links to download sources. Also legally, per the agreements the appliance is not actually sold but leased to the customer.